# Thread - No matching function to call

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a function called send

```
void send ( mutex *m,
            socklen_t addr_size, 
            sockaddr_storage serverStorage,
            double PLP ,
            int size_of_file ,
            char ** char_file , 
            int *total ,
            int *next_seq_to_send ,
            int *base_seq , 
            int client_socket , 
            int *window_size ,  
            vector <packet> *window_buffer , 
            vector <bool> *wind_slots )
```

I want to use this function to create a thread like this

```
std::thread send_thread (send, &m ,addr_size, 
                         serverStorage, PLP , size_of_file,
                         char_file , &total,
                         &next_seq_to_send,  
                         &base_seq, client_socket,   
                         &window_size,&window_buffer, 
                         &wind_slots );
```

But i got an **error**

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::mutex*, socklen_t&, sockaddr_storage&, double&, int&, char*&, int*, int*, int*, int&, int*, std::vector<packet>*, std::vector<bool>*)’
 rage, PLP , size_of_file , char_file , &total , &next_seq_to_send , &base_seq , client_socket , &window_size , &window_buffer , &wind_slots );
                                                                                                                                             ^
```

Any help?

Comment: `std::ref` does not do what you think it does. Stop guessing and read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ref` is used when you need to pass an object into the thread function (or in similar cases) by *reference.* That's not your case, though; the function doesn't accept *references,* it accepts *pointers* (and takes them by value). Just change all your uses of `std::ref(x)` into `&x` to take the arguments' addresses, and you should be good.

Comment: @AlaaOthman do you have other overloads of `send`? The error message seems to indicate so.